# Item Separator while using Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net nuget package to Serialize and Deserialize my data. My only problem is that there is no item separator between the objects. So, if I want to read only one object then it reads all the object from a given offset.
Like in Json if we provide the offset it reads till it finds a valid json object. After that it discards. I want a similar functionality for protobuf.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf - the data format - indeed: does not have anything that explicitly denotes the start/end of an object. This is by design (so that append === merge), and is part of the protocol specification, and is not library specific (every implementation will have the same limitations).

One common option / workaround is to prefix each object with the length, so that you can at least consume multiple objects from a single stream. To do this: see the `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` methods.

Comment: is there a way to deserialize list of objects which are individually serialized by SerializeWithLengthPrefix

Comment: @UtkarshSrivastav what options *exactly* did they use when serialized? in some cases, you can simply use `Deserialize<List<Foo>>` (or similar) and it will be semantically identical.